# ¿Cómo hacer un input que acepte hasta un cierto valor y dos decimales pero sin usar muchos if?

Tags: javascript, html

quería hacer un input que cambie el tamaño del texto aceptase solo las siguientes normas:

- Sea un número entre 0/nada - 1000
- Acepte números decimales pero solo hasta 2 decimales y que se indique con `,` o `.`.

Tengo este codigo:

```js
document.querySelector(".in").addEventListener("input", data);
function data(e) {
  e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/[^0-9\.,]/g, '');
  if (/^,/.test(e.target.value)) {
    e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/,/g, '');
    p.style.fontSize = e.target.value + "px";
  }
  if (/^\./.test(e.target.value)) {
    e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/\./g, '');
    p.style.fontSize = e.target.value + "px";
  }
  if (/1000,/.test(e.target.value)) {
    e.target.value = 1000;
    p.style.fontSize = e.target.value + "px";
  }
  if (/1000\./.test(e.target.value)) {
    e.target.value = 1000;
    p.style.fontSize = e.target.value + "px";
  }
  if (/\.{1,}[0-9]{0,},{1,}/.test(e.target.value)) {
    e.target.value = e.target.value.split("").reverse().join("").replace(/,/, '').split("").reverse().join("");
    p.style.fontSize = e.target.value + "px";
  }
  if (/\,{1,}[0-9]{0,}.{1,}/.test(e.target.value)) {
    e.target.value = e.target.value.split("").reverse().join("").replace(/\./, '').split("").reverse().join("");
    p.style.fontSize = e.target.value + "px";
  }
  if (parseFloat(e.target.value) < 1000) {
    if (e.target.value.includes(',')) {
      if (/,{1}[0-9]{0,},/.test(e.target.value)) {
        e.target.value = e.target.value.split("").reverse().join("").replace(/,/, '').split("").reverse().join("");
        p.style.fontSize = e.target.value + "px";
      }
      if (/,[0-9]{3,}/.test(e.target.value)) {
        e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/[0-9]$/, '');
        p.style.fontSize = e.target.value + "px";
      }
    }
    if (e.target.value.includes('.')) {
      if (/\.{1}[0-9]{0,}\./.test(e.target.value)) {
        e.target.value = e.target.value.split("").reverse().join("").replace(/\./, '').split("").reverse().join("");
        p.style.fontSize = e.target.value + "px";
      }
      if (/\.[0-9]{3,}/.test(e.target.value)) {
        e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/[0-9]$/, '');
        p.style.fontSize = e.target.value + "px";
      }
    }
    p.style.fontSize = Number(e.target.value) + "px";
  }
  if (parseFloat(e.target.value) > 1000) {
    e.target.value = 1000;
    p.style.fontSize = e.target.value + "px";
  }
  if (parseFloat(e.target.value) == "") {
    e.target.value = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(p).fontSize);
  }
  if (parseFloat(e.target.value) < 0) {
    e.target.value = 1;
    p.style.fontSize = e.target.value + "px";
  }
  p.style.marginTop = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(p).marginTop) - 0.01 + "px";
}
```

```html
<input class="in"/>
<p id="p">Texto</p>
```

Me parece muy largo ya que usa muchos `if` y se vuelve lento, me gustaría saber si hay otra forma de hacerlo o sino como puedo hacer el código más corto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con una expresión regular seria suficiente no hay necesidad de hacer demasiados if para esto así:

```
document.querySelector(".in").addEventListener("keypress", e => {
    if(!/^(?:\d{1,3}(?:\,\d{1,2})?(?:\,)?|\s*)$/.test(e.target.value + e.key)) e.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: Ojo con el evento `keypress` está *deprecated* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event

Answer (score 2):

1.- Usas las validaciones de HTML5

- max="1000"
- min="0"
- step="0.01"

2.- Llamas a la validaciones cada vez que el input cambia usando el evento `oninput`

3.- Ejecutas la validación usando la función `checkValidity()`

4.- Vas guardando el valor del campo cada vez que la validación es correcta. La puedes guardar dentro de un atributo `data-` del mismo input. De esta manera, cuando la validación falla retrotraes el valor al último valor que ha aprobado.

```js
function validate(){
  if(event.target.checkValidity()){
    event.target.setAttribute("data-oldvalue", event.target.value);
  }
  else{
    event.target.value = event.target.getAttribute("data-oldvalue") || "";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" min="0" max="1000" step="0.01" oninput="validate()">
```

El único problema es que acepta valores mas de 2 decimales cuando desde el tercer decimal en adelante son ceros, por ejemplo `33,2200000`. Pero te lo dejo para que lo soluciones.

Answer (score 1):

Una versión más segura y optimizada, podrías hacer lo siguiente:

#### Evitar números menor a 0 y mayor a 1000:

Aparte de colocar `min` y `max`, podemos validar que si el valor del input es menor a `0` o mayor a `1000`, hacemos un `slice` desde el primer caracter hasta el penúltimo caracter, removiendo el último y así obteniendo sólo los números correspondientes (que sería de `1` a `1000`):

```js
function data(input) {
  if (input.value < 0 || input.value > 1000) {
    input.value = input.value.slice(0, input.value.length - 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<input class="in" type="number" min="0" max="1000" oninput="data(this)" style="width: 100px;"/>
```

#### Evitar números negativos:

Sin embargo, hasta aquí nos permite ingresar el `-`, y al colocar el siguiente número, recién ocurre el `slice`. Entonces podemos evitarlo haciendo una pequeña validación, donde indico que si presiono la tecla `-`, evitamos el evento por defecto del `keydown`, es decir, no recibirá el valor de la tecla pulsada:

```js
function data(input) {
  if (input.value < 0 || input.value > 1000) {
    input.value = input.value.slice(0, input.value.length - 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<input class="in" type="number" min="0" max="1000" oninput="data(this)"
       onkeydown="if (event.key === '-') event.preventDefault();" style="width: 100px;"/>
```

#### Evitar el onpaste y onDrop:

Incluso podemos volver más seguro el input evitando el pegado y el arrastre, devolviendo `false` cuando ocurren estos eventos:

```js
function data(input) {
  if (input.value < 0 || input.value > 1000) {
    input.value = input.value.slice(0, input.value.length - 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<input class="in" type="number" min="0" max="1000" oninput="data(this)"
       onkeydown="if (event.key === '-') event.preventDefault();"
       onpaste="return false;" onDrop="return false;" style="width: 100px;"/>
```

#### 2 decimales como máximo:

Y respecto a los decimales, si por ejemplo, colocamos el `999` y seguido un decimal, podemos poner infinitos números, tipo `999.9999999999`. Para evitarlo, podemos verificar que si el valor del input incluye un `.`, separamos el valor usando al `.` como separador, obteniendo un array, en donde el primer elemento será el número antes del `.` y el segundo elemento será el número después del `.`. Entonces trabajemos con el segundo elemento, que sería `arr[1]`, y validamos que si su longitud de ese número es mayor a 2, hacemos un `slice` para obtener los dos primeros caracteres, removiendo el tercer caracter y así obteniendo siempre 2 números como decimales. Y luego juntamos los elementos del array con `join()`, que devuelve una cadena y asignamos ese valor al input:

```js
function data(input) {
  if (input.value < 0 || input.value > 1000) {
    input.value = input.value.slice(0, input.value.length - 1);
  }

  if (input.value.includes('.')) {
    let arr = input.value.split('.');
    if (arr[1].length > 2) {
      arr[1] = arr[1].slice(0, 2);
      input.value = arr.join('.');
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input class="in" type="number" min="0" max="1000" oninput="data(this)"
       onkeydown="if (event.key === '-') event.preventDefault();"
       onpaste="return false;" onDrop="return false;" style="width: 100px;"/>
```

---

#### Código final:

```js
function data(input) {
  if (input.value < 0 || input.value > 1000) {
    input.value = input.value.slice(0, input.value.length - 1);
  }

  if (input.value.includes('.')) {
    let arr = input.value.split('.');
    if (arr[1].length > 2) {
      arr[1] = arr[1].slice(0, 2);
      input.value = arr.join('.');
    }
  }

  let p = document.querySelector("#p");
  p.style.fontSize = input.value + "px";
  p.style.marginTop = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(p).marginTop) - 0.01 + "px";
}
```

```html
<input class="in" type="number" min="0" max="1000" oninput="data(this)"
       onkeydown="if (event.key === '-') event.preventDefault();"
       onpaste="return false;" onDrop="return false;" style="width: 100px;"/>

<p id="p">Texto</p>
```