# Límite de clics de una variable llamada cantidad_disponible

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo hago para validar el input cuando la `cantidad_disponible` es `0`, mostrar mensaje y no dejar agregar y si la cantidad es mayor a la `cantidad_disponible` mostrar mensaje?, no se como hacerlo con este codigo con la alternativa de yussef:

```
function addItemToShoppingCart(id_prod, codigo, nombre,cantidad_disponible,talla,talla_ropa) {
    
    //function addItemToShoppingCart(itemTitle, itemPrice, itemImage) {
    
    //const elementsTitle = shoppingCartItemsContainer.getElementsByClassName(
        //'shoppingCartItemTitle'
      //);
      
      const elementsTitle = document.getElementsByClassName('title');
    
      for (let i = 0; i < elementsTitle.length; i++) {
        if (elementsTitle[i].innerText === id_prod) {
          ////let elementQuantity = tbody.querySelector('.ItemCarrito>.table__cantidad>#shoppingCartItemQuantity_'+id_prod);
          ////const cantidad_disponible = parseInt(elementQuantity.getAttribute("max"));
         ////elementQuantity.value=cantidad_disponible
          // elementQuantity.value++;
          //console.log(elementQuantity.value)
          //mensaje exitoso
          updateShoppingCartTotal();
          return;
        }
      }
    
      const tr = document.createElement('tr')
        tr.classList.add('ItemCarrito')
         tr.setAttribute("id", `tr_${id_prod}`);
    // // //     <td class="table__productos">
             
    // // //     <input type="text" id="id_productos" disabled style="border: none; border-color: transparent;outline: 0;width: 40px;
    // // // " name="id_productos" class="id_productos" value="${item.id}"></>
    // // //       <h6 class="title" hidden>${item.id}</h6>
          
    // // //       </td>
      Content = `
         <th scope="row">${id_prod}</th>
    
         <td class="table__productos">
         <input id="id_productos_${id_prod}" type="text" value="${id_prod}" class="id_productos"
        style="border: none; border-color: transparent;outline: 0;width: 40px;">
    
           <h6 id="title_${id_prod}" class="title" hidden>${id_prod}</h6>
         </td>
    
        <td class="table__codigo">
        <input id="codigo_${id_prod}" type="text" value="${codigo}" class="codigo"
         style="border: none; border-color: transparent;outline: 0;width: 40px;">
          
         </td>
    
        <td class="table__nombre">
       <input id="nombre_${id_prod}" type="text" value="${nombre}" class="nombre"
       style="border: none; border-color: transparent;outline: 0;width: 40px;">
         
         </td>
        
         <td class="table__cantidad_disponible">
         <input id="cantidad_disponible_${id_prod}" type="text" value="${cantidad_disponible}" class="cantidad_disponible"
         style="border: none; border-color: transparent;outline: 0;width: 40px;">
          
        </td>
    
        <td class="table__talla">
        <input id="talla_${id_prod}" type="text" value="${talla}" class="talla"
       style="border: none; border-color: transparent;outline: 0;width: 40px;">
          
         </td>
    
         <td class="table__talla_ropa">
        <input id="talla_ropa_${id_prod}"  type="text" value="${talla_ropa}" class="talla_ropa"
         style="border: none; border-color: transparent;outline: 0;width: 40px;">
          
        </td>
    
    
    
        
        
        <td class="table__cantidad">
                    <input id="shoppingCartItemQuantity_${id_prod}" max="${cantidad_disponible}" oninput="updateCantidad(this)" class="shopping-cart-quantity-input shoppingCartItemQuantity_" type="number"
                        value="1" min="1">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger buttonDelete" type="button">X</button>
                    </td>
            
         `
       
        
       tr.innerHTML = Content 
         tbody.append(tr)
        
    }
```

con el codigo expuesto del usuario Yussef

Comment: lo que nose es como cambiar el this por el input que necesito

Answer (score 0):

A mi para validar campos numéricos me gusta usar `checkValidity`, puedes ver esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/597853/301324) si tienes dudas

Tu tienes esta secuencia `input -> oninput -> updateCantidad` y funciona cuando el usuario modifica el valor del input. Pero el evento `oninput` no se ejecuta cuando el valor ha sido cambiado por código

Entonces debes crear una función "Add" que añada +1 (o el valor que tu requieres), por ejemplo

```
function add(id, cantidad=1){
  let input = document.getElementById("shoppingCartItemQuantity_" + id);
  input.value= input.valueAsNumber + cantidad;
  updateCantidad(input);
}
```

Esta función recibirá como argumento la `id` del input y opcionalmente la cantidad a agregar (obviamente si pasas un negativo quitará en vez de agregar). Además se ejecutará manualmente la función `updateCantidad`

Aquí un ejemplo completo:

***(Vez como si es posible crear un ejemplo mínimo y verificable!!!!!)***

```js
function updateCantidad(input) {
  if(input.checkValidity()){
   input.setAttribute("data-oldvalue", input.value);
  }
  else{
    input.value = input.getAttribute("data-oldvalue") || input.min;
  }
}
function add(id, cantidad=1){
  let input = document.getElementById("shoppingCartItemQuantity_" + id);
  input.value= input.valueAsNumber + cantidad;
  updateCantidad(input);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="add('1')" >Añadir</button>
<button onclick="add('1',-1)" >quitar</button>
<input id="shoppingCartItemQuantity_1" max="10" min="1" oninput="updateCantidad(this)" type="number" value="1" >

<br>
<button onclick="add('2')" >Añadir</button>
<button onclick="add('2',-1)" >quitar</button>
<input id="shoppingCartItemQuantity_2" max="10" min="1" oninput="updateCantidad(this)" type="number" value="1" >


<br>
<button onclick="add('3')" >Añadir</button>
<button onclick="add('3',-1)" >quitar</button>
<input id="shoppingCartItemQuantity_3" max="10" min="1" oninput="updateCantidad(this)" type="number" value="1" >
```

Esto llevado a tu código sería:

```
printf('<td class="td"><button onclick="add('.$e->id_productos.')" class="button">Añadir</button></td>');


 <input id="shoppingCartItemQuantity_${id_prod}" max="${cantidad_disponible}" oninput="updateCantidad(this)" class="shopping-cart-quantity-input shoppingCartItemQuantity_" type="number" value="1" min="1" >


    function updateCantidad(input) {
      if(input.checkValidity()){
       input.setAttribute("data-oldvalue", input.value);
      }
      else{
        input.value = input.getAttribute("data-oldvalue") || input.min;
      }
    }
    function add(id, cantidad=1){
      let input = document.getElementById("shoppingCartItemQuantity_" + id);
      input.value= input.valueAsNumber + cantidad;
      updateCantidad(input);
    }
```

Comment: Sabes Yussef, no me funciona me trae null en esta parte input.valueAsNumber resulta que el elemento se crea al 1er click con cantidad por defecto un uno

Comment: Entra a https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146964/yssef y pégame el código que has puesto

Comment: ok, yusssef, te hable hace poco

Comment: Yussef u otro usuario, como hago para validar el input, cuando la cantidad_disponible es 0, moatrar mensaje y no dejar agregar y si la cantidad es mayor a la cantidad_disponible moxtrzr mensaje, nose como hacerlo con este codigo con la alternativa de yussef